# IONIC 2 File Plugin

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

Im using IONIC 2 and trying to use the cordova file plugin from here https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/

My goal is to save a file to the device and load it at a later stage.

The issue I'm having right now is that I have installed the plugin but when using this code..

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    const dataDirectory: string = File.dataDirectory;
    File.checkDir(dataDirectory, 'mydir').then(_ => console.log('yay')).catch(err => console.log('boooh'));

  }
```

I get an error from typescript in my ide saying "Property 'dataDirectory' does not exist on type 'typeof File'"

Comment: Are you running this code after platform.ready() has fired?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue some days ago. It's a bug in the Typescript interface or the documentation. Here's how you can make it work (pseudo code, watch out for the cordova declaration ):

```
declare let cordova: any;

...

export class FileService {

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      ...cordova.file.dataDirectory...
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Native Storage. Works perfectly for me when I'm trying to remember unique userId from Authentication.
Try this : http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/native-storage/